# Creating several dichotomous variables by changing the condition in a loop

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I want to create several variables, 0/1, that meet a condition with a varying cutoff point. Using an interval of 50 to 100, I'd like to create a 0/1 variable for every point in between those two numbers, where 0 is less than and everything else is 1.

For example:

`data1$V1<-ifelse(data1$Value<50, 0, 1)`

where `data1$Value` has the information for the interval and `data1$V1` is the first binary vector using 50 as a cutoff, but then `data1$V2` would be 51, and so forth.

Some reproducible code as a starter:

```
    data1<-data.frame(Value=sample(1:120, 50, replace=TRUE))
    data1$V1<-ifelse(data1$Value<50, 0, 1)
    data1$V2<-ifelse(data1$Value<51, 0, 1)
    data1$V3<-ifelse(data1$Value<52, 0, 1)
```

How can I do this with a loop?

Comment: @RonakShah added it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, this will work you:

```
data1<-data.frame(Value=sample(1:120, 50, replace=TRUE))

r <- 1:50
vars <- paste0('V', r)
const <- 50

for (i in seq_along(vars)){
  data1[[vars[i]]] <- ifelse(data1$Value<const+i-1, 0, 1)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `lapply` for each value in `interval` and create new columns by comparing it with `data1$Value`

```
interval <- 50:100
cols <- paste0("V", seq_along(interval))
data1[cols] <- lapply(interval, function(x) as.integer(data1$Value >= x))
```

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
data1<-data.frame(Value=sample(1:120, 50, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: Why does `data1[cols]` work? I would have thought it would have thrown an error unless you added a comma to tell it its columns you are working with e.g. `data1[, cols]`?

Comment: @user63230 to select columns for dataframe both `data1[cols]` and `data1[, cols]` work but for matrices only `mat1[, cols]` would work.

Comment: but if you wanted to exact `Value` column above you would need a comma: `data1[, c("Value")]`? `data1[Value]` wouldn't work so does this only refer to `lapply` or just the fact that your `cols` is a character vector?

Comment: it works for character values. One difference while extracting is that `data1[, "Value"]` returns a vector whereas `data1["Value"]` returns a dataframe. Check for `mtcars` data `class(mtcars["cyl"])` and `class(mtcars[, "cyl"])`

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this. The cutoff point is included in the new variable Name!

```
cutoff <- c(50:100)
for (i in cutoff){
     eval(parse(text=paste0("data1$V_", i, "<- ifelse(data1$Value <", i, ", 0, 1)")))
}
```